# How to Keep Slider and Image in one row under the banner in html page

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have added BxSlider v4.0 in the web pages.
The Slider used to cover the screen, i.e. width is 1090px.
Below to it one image is there of 240*220px.
I am facing problem to integrate both the same slider and image in one row.
Slider will be 830px*250px and image will be 240*250px.
Please help.

BxSlider v4.0 link [jquery.bxslider.css](http://code.google.com/p/reshapeandrevive/source/browse/trunk/js/jquery.bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css?r=23)

Slider.php

```
<div class="slide_show">
<div class="bxsl">
       <!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<script>
$jbx = jQuery.noConflict();
 $jbx(document).ready(function(){
  $jbx('.bxslider').bxSlider({auto: true,
  autoControls: true,mode: 'horizontal',
  captions: false});

});
</script>
<script>
    $pop = jQuery.noConflict();
    $pop(document).ready(function(){
    $pop("#pop_info").slideDown("slow");
    });
    function hide_it(){
    $hd = jQuery.noConflict();
    $hd("#pop_info").hide("slow");
    }
</script>
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="images/design/ayurveda_banner.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/design/banner_inner.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/design/banner-ayurveda.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/design/inn_pro_banner.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/design/inn_pro_banner.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/design/inn_pro_banner.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
</div></div>
```

Style.css

```
> slide_show{width:1100px;float:left;min-height:200px;position:relative;}
.bxsl{float:left;width:830px;min-height:200px;}
.center{float:left;width:1090px;min-height:200px;margin-top:5px;}
```

Index.php

```
<?php include('inc/slider.php');?>
<div class="center">
<img src="images/design/indigo.jpg" style="float:right;width:240px;height:250px;border:1px solid #f6f6f6;margin:1px 1px 1px 2px; ">
```

Answer (score 0):

First I think your style.css has the following errors

the > slideshow should be .slide_show and the class name for bxslider should not be bxsl

and then add the following

```
display: inline-block;
width: 840px;
vertical-align: top;
```

to `.slide_show` class and

```
display: inline-block;
width: 240px;
vertical-align: top;
```

to `.center` class

I am not 100% confident I understood your code because you have `width:1090px` in the center classs

Comment: No this is not working. If I will add table to both the slider and image, how will it be??

Comment: Do you have a live URL